# How to add a reader macro to Python?

Tags: python

### Background

In Verilog, I can specify binary numbers using expressions including underscores.  For example:

```
12'b1100_0111_0001 == 12'b110001110001  // The underscores are ignored
```

I find this a nice feature and would like to add it to Python so I can write something like:

```
x = 0b1100_0111_0001
y = 0x3fff_cc00
```

In Lisp, I could do this using something like *set-dispatch-macro-character* to be able to edit the source before it is compiled by means of a reader macro.

### Question

What is a good way of adding a Lisp-like reader macro in Python?

I would be equally happy with suggestions to fix the problems with my current approach or with a completely different approach.

### What I've tried

I've tried adding a custom finder object to sys.meta_path.  This almost works except for two problems:

1. When I import a module with my custom finder, it doesn't store a pyc compiled representation of the file
2. Ideally I would like the reader macro to apply to the rest of the toplevel file, rather than have to put my code into a separate file "verilog_test_code.py"

### Source code

**verilog_test_code.py**

```
def run_test():
    return 0b1100_0111_0001+0x3fff_cc00
```

**toplevel.py**

```
import remove_underscores
import verilog_test_code
print verilog_test_code.run_test()
```

**remove_underscores.py**

```
import tokenize,sys,imp

def remove_underscores(src):
    """Remove underscores from hexadecimals."""
    result = []
    g = tokenize.generate_tokens(src.readline)   
    for toknum, tokval, _, _, _  in g:
        if toknum == tokenize.NAME and tokval[0]=='_' and result and result[-1][0]==tokenize.NUMBER:
            result[-1][1] = str(result[-1][1]) + tokval[1:].replace('_','')
        else:
            result.append([toknum, tokval])
    return tokenize.untokenize(result)


class my_finder_loader(object):

    def is_package(self, fullname):
        return False

    def get_code(self, fullname):
        return compile(self.get_source(fullname),fullname,'exec')

    def get_source(self, fullname):
        (src, pathname, description) = imp.find_module(fullname)
        srctext = remove_underscores(src)
        src.close()
        return srctext

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        if fullname in sys.modules:
            return sys.modules[fullname]
        code = self.get_code(fullname)
        mod = sys.modules.setdefault(fullname, imp.new_module(fullname))
        mod.__file__ = "<%s>" % self.__class__.__name__
        mod.__loader__ = self
        mod.__package__ = ''
        exec(code, mod.__dict__)
        return mod

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None): 
        if not fullname.startswith('verilog_'):
            return None
        return self

sys.meta_path.append(my_finder_loader())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class BinaryUnderscorifier(object):

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return int(name.replace('_', ''), 2)

b = BinaryUnderscorifier()

print b._1100_0111_0001 == 0b110001110001       # prints "True"
```

Of course, the disassembly of `b._1100_0111_0001` is very different from that of `0b110001110001`, which may be e.g. a performance hit for you, but hopefully not.

Comment: It's important that the binary part start with `_`. Otherwise, it won't parse correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is not what you're looking for, but I found it fun to create.

None of this is recommended.

First I used a modified version of [this Infix pattern](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122-infix-operators/). Here's my code for this part:

```
class Infix(object):
    """
    Instances of this class can be treated like an infix operator
    by enclosing them with <<.>>.
    """
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
    def __rlshift__(self, other):
        return Infix(lambda x, self=self, other=other: self.function(other, x))
    def __rshift__(self, other):
        return self.function(other)
    def __call__(self, value1, value2):
        return self.function(value1, value2)
```

After that, I defined `_` to be an `Infix` that accepts a `bin` on the left and an `int` on the right, figures out the relevant digits, and makes them into the combined `bin`. It's not pretty and I would be happy to hear advice on making the `lambda` that I used more sane.

```
In [247]: _ = Infix(lambda x,y: bin(int(bin(int(x))[2:]+str(y),2)))

In [248]: 0b1101 <<_>> 1001
Out[248]: '0b11011001'
```

**Note** that if you use this in IPython or other fancy editors, the `_` variable may already be defined. For example, in IPython, `_` is overwritten with the most recent console output each time you execute a command, so you cannot effectively ghost `_` as this `Infix` operator in such a situation, and you'll have to repeatedly redefine `_`.

But if you're not working in a situation like that, this should provide at least some kind of an infix syntactic trick to let you write `bin` instances this way.

This works by overriding the bit-shift operators. It would be a lot of fun if it was possible to override the "is-lexically-adjacent-to" operation, like the way function application happens in Lisp or Haskell.